# How can I load a local json file in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

In my SvelteKit app ,I have some data stored in a json file at `/static/data.json`, an array of objects in json format.

I need to retrieve the data in one of my pages at `/src/routes/test/test.svelte`. Here's my code at the top of the file.

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload() {
        const response = await this.fetch("data.json");
        const jsonRes = await response.json();

        return {
            props: {
                testData: jsonRes,
            },
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let testData;

    console.log(testData);
</script>
```

I get undefined in the console.

Do you know what I did wrong ? I tried to use load too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that the file is called `testData.json`, then you should fetch `'/testData.json'`.

(In newer versions of SvelteKit the function should be called `load` and `fetch` is to be retrieved from the function argument instead of from `this`.)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the file is called `data.json`. I tried to make your changes but I get an error `unexpected token in JSON at position 0`.

Comment: Look at the browser dev tools, the network panel will show what the request actually returned. You can also use the debugger to stop before the `.json()` and check out the `.text()` instead. Also, make sure to actually include the `/` otherwise the path will be relative to the current page.

Comment: Adding `/` in the path worked. Thanks a lot.